# secure session cookie not working

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to secure my cookie in php using http only and secure attributes. However using this remember me functionality is not working.

here is what I have used.

```
ob_start();
session_name('XYZ');
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
```

and using below code to set my cookie..

```
setcookie($pureSiteNm . 'userName', $userName, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/', null, true, true);
setcookie($pureSiteNm . 'password', $entered_pass, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/', null, true, true);
setcookie($pureSiteNm . 'rememberme', 'y', time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/', null, true, true);
```

retriving as below..

```
$_COOKIE[$pureSiteNm . "password"]
```

but when I log out I am not able to retrieve the cookie again in login page. Any hint will do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. I was trying to set cookie as secure even if my server didn't have https.

so changing

```
setcookie($pureSiteNm . 'userName', $userName, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/', null, true, true);
```

to

```
setcookie($pureSiteNm . 'userName', $userName, time() + 3600 * 24 * 30, '/', null, isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
```

worked for me... Hope it may help you guys..